# What is the best strategy for escaping Tall Birds?

Tags: dont-starve

Frequently, I make the mistake of getting too close to a Tall Bird nest, mostly by stumbling upon it in an unexplored area.   I haven't been successful at defeating them, so I run.

It seems to me that Tall Birds chase you farther than any of the other mobs I've encountered.

I've been able to put some distance between us by zig-zagging which makes it stop to attack every time you change directions, and allowing you to run farther away.

Is there any other way to get them to stop chasing you?  Anything you can drop?  Or a biome they won't enter?  Or, any other stratgey?

Comment: When they're chasing you, are you currently holding an egg which was stolen from their nest? :P

Comment: Not always!  They're just a nasty breed of bloodthirsty bird!

Comment: I only ask because I've only ever had them follow me a few steps *unless* I had the egg. Then they'd chase me indefinitely.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not certain. But, I seem to recall not having an egg the last time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tallbirds are beautiful creatures, but a bit territorial. They'll follow for quite a bit when you've come too near, and they'll follow you for a very long time if you've stolen their egg.

Escaping Tallbirds is hard. Get as much distance as you can between yourself and their nest, eventually they'll give up. Killing them might be easier:

### One at the time

- One bird at the time, one hit at the time.
- There is a little time between his charge (eyes turn red, starting to
  attack) and his actual attack (and the dealing damage). Use this time
  to step out of his damage radius.
- Then, after he attacked the ground, rush back, hit him once, and run off again.
- Repeat.

After about 12 hits with a spear (you can do the last 2 at the same time without time in between), he'll be dead and you'll have 2 meat (and free access to his never spoiling, hatchable egg).

Warning: when the bird turns around to retreat, don't blindly follow - he might hit without advanced warning. Keep a bit of distance until he decides to attack.

Don't burn the nests, the meat and eggs are too great to forego.

Comment: Since when are those NASTY creatures *beautiful*?  Well, perhaps right *after* you kill them… Thanks for the answer!  I'll try it at earliest convenience!